# Filter DataTable using ArrayList

Tags: asp.net, filter, datatable, arraylist

i have a array list of unique Ids

```
ex 1,2,3,4....
```

and a DataTable with Records with the above IDs

```
ID    Name
1     abc
2     xxx
3     aaa
4     bbb
5     eee
6     fff
```

i need to filter the data table as per the array list content

```
ex: if array list contain 1,2
```

then the DataTable should be filtered only to contain those two records.is there any option on DataTable that i could do this other than running the DataTable inside For Loop and getting each DataRow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Linq to filter and potentially create a new DataTable.

```
var filtered = 
    table.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(r => list.Contains(r.Field<int>("ID")))
        .CopyToDataTable();
```

Given a list containing { 1, 2 }, the filtered table will contain the rows { { 1, "abc" }, { 2, "xxx" } }

Side note: While you can use ArrayLists, it is preferrable to use the generic counterpart `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` in new code written in .NET. Generics were introduced as part of .NET 2.0 / C# 2.0 / VB 8 / Visual Studio 2005. The present editions on the market are .NET 4.0 /  C# 4.0 / VB 10 / Visual Studio 2010. ArrayLists are effectively obsolete except in the case of supporting code originating in earlier versions of the langauge and framework.

Also, if the list is particularly large, it might be worth first loading it into a `HashSet<T>` prior to the query, as it will be more performant when using a Contains method.

---

Full working code demonstration:

```
var table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
table.Rows.Add(1, "abc");
table.Rows.Add(2, "xxx");
table.Rows.Add(3, "aaa");
table.Rows.Add(4, "bbb");
table.Rows.Add(5, "eee");
table.Rows.Add(6, "fff");

// var list = new ArrayList(); // do not prefer
var list = new List<int>();
list.Add(1);
list.Add(2);

var filtered =
    table.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(r => list.Contains(r.Field<int>("ID")))
        .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: i'm getting the exception -"The source contains no DataRows." but still the DataTable Has the IDs in the ArrayList

Comment: That error will only occur if the source table has no rows *or* none of them pass the predicate in the where. So either your original table is empty, or it's not matching the values in your list. You will have to debug to verify. I am posting a full snippet of code to demonstrate the working behavior.

Comment: as you mentioned i started using the List<int> now it's working.according to above filtering method the DataTable filtering code requires exactly the integer items on the list.thanx for the help..